# I am unable to install epson thermal printer nuget from nuget package manager console

Tags: c#, wpf, thermal-printer, epson

I have to use epson thermal printer with my wpf application, but i downloaded the sdk code.but when i install epson from package manager console command in my visual studio it is giving me below error.

Install-Package Epson.Epos.Epos2 -Version 2.7.0

i search alot on internet but could not find any clue, please guide me or share some help.

```
Package 'Epson.Epos.Epos2.2.7.0' does not exist in project 'My-WPF-POS'
Package 'Epson.Epos.Epos2.2.7.0' does not exist in folder 'D:\Projects    
\My-WPF-POS-Dir\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 1.4 sec
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Epson.Epos.Epos2 2.7.0'. You                    
are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain   
any assembly references or content files that are compatible 
with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
```

+ Install-Package Epson.Epos.Epos2 -Version 2.7.0

I want to install epson thermal printer from nuget manager and then i want to integrate it with my POS software.

thanks

Comment: the error seems pretty clear.  You are compiling for.net 4.6 and its not compatible with that.

Comment: but if i change the framework to 4.0,4.5,4.6,4.7, it shows the same error. and if i change to 4.5 or 4.0,some code will not work and throws error.

Comment: You need to find out what version its supposed to work with, rather than guess

Comment: but it shows only windows 8,10 compatiblity no other details are available on its website

Comment: Then Id suggest you contact the author, as looking in the nuget package I didnt see a .net version info type thing

Comment: `Epson.Epos.Epos2` is for UWP apps. It's not compatible with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The `Epson.Epos.Epos2` NuGet package targets UWP. It's not compatible with WPF.

There seems to be a .NET (WPF compatible) version available for download at [the official website](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=39). I suggest that you try this one. Either way, you won't be able to use `Epson.Epos.Epos2` in a WPF application.